# teamcity - post tests rerun - update list of testmethods shown on 'Tests' tab to the ones that actually failed in rerun too

Tags: testing, teamcity

I am using Teamcity for running regression tests. Some of the tests are flaky and difficult to make stable, hence I added a rerun step to run the failed once again. I could find the Teamcity service messages to update the buildstatus if all the tests in rerun passed. But the tests tab for the build still shows the failed tests(which failed in first run). Is there a way to update the tests shown under this tab to only the ones which actually failed i.e. the ones that failed in rerun too.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the problem by playing around with the xml file specified in build features (XML report processing)